# ABAP Open SQL SELECT statement displaying all linked materials to my documents

Tags: abap, sap-erp, opensql

The following is the case: I'm using the `DRAD` and `DRAW` SAP tables. I would like to receive all linked material links per documents.

I have: `DRAD` (only relevant columns are shown):

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║  doknr   ║ dokob    ║ objky ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 1        ║     MARA ║  1234 ║
║ 2        ║     MARA ║  5678 ║
║ 1        ║     MARA ║  5678 ║
║ 3        ║     DOC  ║  4444 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

`DRAW` (only relevant columns are shown):

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║  doknr   ║    name  ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬
║ 1        ║   test1  ║
║ 2        ║   test2  ║
║ 3        ║   test3  ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

How do I select a result like:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║  doknr   ║    objky ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬
║ 1        ║   1234   ║
║ 1        ║   5678   ║
║ 2        ║   5678   ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Why don't you want to select doknr = 3 from DRAW? Because the dokob is not 'MARA'?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I dont want to select doknr = 3 cause its not MARA. I only want to select all linked MARA objects

Comment: Are you really asking for `SELECT * FROM drad WHERE dokob = 'MARA'`? Isn't it very simple?

Comment: @SandraRossi Yes it is. I get little confused yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, table `DRAW` is not necessary, you just need `DRAD`

```
SELECT FROM drad
       FIELDS doknr, objky
       WHERE dokob = 'MARA'
       INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_drad).
```